# Where can I find Hunter's Journal Part 2?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the Act 2 lore books?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69789/where-are-the-act-2-lore-books)

I'm having some trouble finding a lore book in Act II - Hunter's Journal Part 2. It's not in my lore list either.

Which zone is this particular book found in?

Answer (score 1):

The order you find these journals depends on the order you visit the locations in Act 2, but the 6 journals can be found in stachels in Hidden Aqueducts, Forgetten Ruins, Vault of the Assassin, Cave of the Betrayer and in the Archives of Zoltun Kulle.

I would start at the Aqueducts and start moving forward, I was able to retrieve them all with little difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

I found it in a corridor of the Ancient Waterway during the Act II quest Blood and Sand. This is the same quest that unlocks the Jeweler.