# Where do the enemies for the unique enemy achievements spawn?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

For the achievement *Never Seen That Before*, you need to kill one of the listed unique enemies. For the achievement *Special Snowflakes*, you need to kill 15 of these same listed unique enemies. For the achievement *A Unique Collection*, you need to kill all of these listed unique enemies. Where are they usually found (what zones, and in what general directions/areas within those zones)? Do some spawn more predictably than others?

[image: Special Snowflakes]

Comment: This is going to be huge!

Comment: Are locations of these champions unique at all?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are 82 of these and they are all found randomly. I've added all the ones that I've confirmed personally to start with plus those listed on [the Diablo 3 database](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/special-snowflakes) that I've verified on other sites. For the sake of completeness and simplicity, I'm posting this as a community wiki post so that people can add what they find:

### Act I

- **Bellybloat the Scarred**, Infected Monstrosity - Cathedral Level 4
- **Captain Cage**, Commander of the Dead - Cathedral Level 4
- **Cudgelarm**, Undead Mauler - Cathedral Level 2
- **Dreadclaw the Leaper**, Rodent of Unusual Size - Fields of Misery
- **Drury Brown**, Thief of Bones - Defiled Crypt
- **Ebenezer Samuel**, Deceased Scribe - Old Tristram Road / Mass Grave
- **Fecklar's Ghost**, Horror of the Shadows - The Festering Woods
- **Firestarter**, Burn to a Cinder - Cathedral Level 2
- **Jezeb the Conjuror**, Cultist Beast Caller - Leoric's Manor
- **Logrut the Warrior**, Fierce Moon Clan Fighter - Highlands Crossing / Southern Highlands
- **Lorzak the Powerful**, Bearer of Frost - Southern Highlands
- **Lucious the Depraved**, Thief of Corpses - Cemetery of the Forsaken
- **Mange**, Vicious Infected Beast - The Weeping Hollow
- **Merrium Skullthorn**, Plagued Skeletal Fighter - Cathedral Level 2
- **Qurash the Reviled**, Plaguespinner - Caverns of Araneae
- **Ragus Grimlow**, Gorged Undead Brother - Cathedral Level 1
- **Rathlin the Widowmaker**, Plagueweaver - Caves of Aranae
- **Red Rock**, Heart of Fire - Southern Highlands
- **Sarella the Vile**, Cruel Servant of the Coven - Leoric's Manor Courtyard
- **Venimite**, Tiny and Deadly - Caverns of Araneae
- **Zhelobb the Venomous**, Broodspawn of the Queen - Caverns of Araneae

### Act II

- **Ashek**, Diminutive Fallen Fighter - Black Canyon Mines
- **Beyatt**, The Elusive One - Stinging Winds, Lost Caravan subarea
- **Blarg the Imp**, Frenetic Fiery Creature - Desolate Sands
- **Bloodfeather**, Winged Desert Predator - Desolate Sands
- **Gart the Mad**, Maniacal Fallen Master - Howling Plateau
- **Hazzor the Viper**, The Sibilant - Sewers of Caldeum
- **Hellscream**, The Render - The Unknown Depths
- **High Cultist Murdos**, Cruel and Powerful Cult Acolyte - Alcarnus
- **Mage Lord Caustus**, Guardian Lord of Poison - The Storm Halls
- **Mage Lord Flaydren**, Guardian Lord of Lightning - The Storm Halls
- **Mage Lord Ghuyan**, Guardian Lord of Fire - The Storm Halls
- **Mage Lord Skomara**, Guardian Lord of Frost - The Storm Halls
- **Otzi the Cursed**, Infected Creature of Death - Eastern Channel
- **Raiha the Vicious**, Swiftness of a Cat - Desolate Sands
- **Razormouth**, Terror of the Sand - Black Canyon Mines
- **Saha the Slasher**, Infected Terrifying Claws - Howling Plateau
- **Sammash**, Coven Thug - Alcarnus
- **Shondar the Invoker**, Master of the Threshold - Alcarnus
- **Stinging Death Swarm**, Relentless Cloud of Pain - Eastern Channel / Western Channel
- **The Archivist**, Dark Lorekeeper - The Unknown Depths
- **Thrum**, Giant Stone Mauler - Realm of Shadow
- **Torsar**, Storm of the Desert - Dahlgur Oasis
- **Yakara**, Savage Serpent Warrior - Eastern Channel
- **Yeth**, Hound of Pestilence - Road to Alcarnus

### Act III

- **Axegrave the Executioner**, Heads Will Roll - The Keep Depths Level 2
- **Axgore the Cleaver**, Lord of the Phasebeasts - Core of Arreat
- **Bashface the Truncheon**, Powerful Demon Warrior - Stonefort
- **Belagg Pierceflesh**, Bone and Arrow - The Keep Depths Level 3
- **Blarg the Foul**, Diseased Warrior Brute - Bridge of Korsikk
- **Captain Dale**, Former Guard Captain - The Keep Depths Level 1
- **Charuch the Spear**, Deadly Blood Clan Ranger - Tower of the Cursed level 1
- **Chiltara**, Vile Frost Stalker - Caverns of Frost Level 2
- **Demonika the Wicked**, From the Heart of Hell - Tower of the Damned Level 1
- **Direclaw the Demonflyer**, Swift Winged Death - Rakkis Crossing
- **Dreadgrasp**, Tendrils of Evil - The Battlefields
- **Gholash**, Savage Fiery Brute - Tower of the Damned Level 1
- **Gormungandr**, Serpent of Arreat - Arreat Crater Level 1
- **Gorog the Bruiser**, One-Thousand Pounder - The Core of Arreat
- **Growlfang**, Bite Much Worse Than Bark - Arreat 1
- **Gugyn the Gauntlet**, Impassable Barrier - The Keep Depths Level 3
- **Haxxor**, Wielder of Giant Axes - Tower of the Cursed Level 2
- **Hyrug the Malformed**, Forgotten Scourge - Tower of the Cursed Level 1
- **Lummock the Brute**, Enraged Bone Breaker - Rakkis Crossing
- **Marchocyas**, Winged Horror - Skycrown Battlements
- **Mehsak the Abomination**, From the Depths of Arreat - The Battlefields
- **Riplash**, Thief of Souls - Tower of the Damned Level 2
- **Severclaw**, Fiery Crawler - Arreat Crater Level 1
- **Shandra'Har**, Vile Plagued Conjuror - Rakkis Crossing
- **The Crusher**, Just Passin' By - Tower of the Damned Level 2
- **Thornback**, Spiked Fire Beast - The Keep Depths Level 1
- **Vicious Gray Turkey**, Delicious Armored Beast - The Keep Depths Level 3

### Act IV

- **Grimnight the Soulless**, Shadow of Death - Silver Spire Level 2
- **Haures**, Hand of Ruin - Silver Spire Level 2
- **Khatun**, Sky Terror - Gardens of Hope 1st tier
- **Kysindra the Wretched**, Lust's Forlorn - Silver Spire Level 1
- **Pyres the Damned**, Eternity of Fire - Silver Spire Level 1
- **Rhau'Kye**, The Eye of Flame - Silver Spire Level 2
- **Sao'Thall**, Embodiment of Hatred - Silver Spire Level 2
- **Slarg the Behemoth**, Massive Hellbeast - Silver Spire Level 1
- **Torchlighter**, Breath of Flame - Gardens of Hope 2nd Tier (Possibly 1st Tier)
- **Veshan the Fierce**, Cloaked by the Unseen - Gardens of Hope 1st Tier

If you edit the lists above, please note the specific area and sub-area where you found them.

Comment: https://github.com/givanse/d3tools

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Since skovacs1 posted another list, I am only updating this one with a few that I personally find. I may reorganize this to be more generally useful in future.

I found an incomplete list on the [Diablo III database](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/special-snowflakes)

### Act I

- Bellybloat the Scarred, Infected Monstrosity - Cathedral Level 4
- Dreadclaw the Leaper, Rodent of Unusual Size - Fields of Misery
- Drury Brown, Thief of Bones - Defiled Crypt
- Venimite - Caverns of Araenae (credit Tetu on d3db)
- Gorog the Bruiser - Southern Highlands ([credit to Lunco](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/70596/25150))
- Lorzak the Powerful, Bearer of Frost - Southern Highlands
- Lucious the Depraved, Thief of Corpses - Cemetery of the Forsaken
- Mange, Vicious Infected Beast - The Weeping Hollow

### Act II

- Ashek, Diminutive Fallen Fighter - Black Canyon Mines
- Beyatt, The Elusive One - Stinging Winds, Lost Caravan subarea
- Bloodfeather, Winged Desert Predator - Desolate Sands
- Razormouth, Terror of the Sand - Black Canyon Mines
- The Archivist, Dark Lorekeeper - The Unknown Depths
- Thrum, Giant Stone Mauler - Realm of Shadow

### Act III

- Axegrave the Executioner, Heads Will Roll - The Keep Depths Level 2
- Axgore the Cleaver, Lord of the Phasebeasts - Core of Arreat
- Blarg the Foul, Diseased Warrior Brute - Bridge of Korsikk
- Chiltara, Vile Frost Stalker - Caverns of Frost Level 2
- Dreadgrasp, Tendrils of Evil - The Battlefields
- Growlfang, Bite Much Worse Than Bark - Skycrown Battlements
- Gugyn the Gauntlet, Impassable Barrier - The Keep Depths Level 3

### Act IV

- Sao'Thall, Embodiment of Hatred - Silver Spire Level 2
- Torchlighter, Breath of Flame - Guardens of Hope 2nd tier

---

Everyone questing for the Staff of Herding is going to kill Chiltara, he drops the gibbering gemstone. Another post I read places Beyatt in Black Canyon Mines.

Answer (score 1):

These are all random quest mobs found all over Diablo. They all spawn in their own territories but not always, basically just a random quest generator. There's usually a bit of story or a rare chest and then you kill them as the boss.

Gorog the Bruiser spawns after the Spider Queen in goat territory when you are looking for the staff. I only remember this guy because he had a mechanic I hadn't seen before - if he continuously hit me he hit harder and harder.

I've killed 7 more but don't remember their locations by their name. I know there's one or two in Desecrated Fields.

Comment: I just encountered Gorog the Bruiser a few minutes ago and it was a Colossal Golgor right before I fought Azmodan in Act 3, Core of Areat. I think maybe you have the name confused.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't directly found the ones missing from the list above, but I have found a few references on other sites and then went through the game strings to narrow down the rest.  In the case of strings, I looked the unique up on http://www.d3lexicon.com/, looked at the base of the string, went to that entry to find the enemy's name, then looked up that enemy in [D3DB](http://d3db.com/) to find the zones it can spawn in.  Keep in mind that if [D3DB](http://d3db.com/) is missing spawn zones for the enemy type, or if the unique appears in a zone where its enemy type does not, then these zones might be a waste of time.  (Off the top of my head, I could have sworn Enslaved Nightmares could spawn on Silver Spire level 1 as well, but I can't check right now because of maintenance.)  It's also possible some of these also spawn in the more rare dungeons, and only there.  But it's a **starting point**.  Please do not assume you will actually find the unique in the zones listed, only use this info if it's the only info you've got.

Edit: I asked the administrator of D3Inferno.com if there is any way to read the spawn zones from the game data, and he told me there is not, because that information is held server-side.  So until someone actually finds a unique monster, this is the best we can do.

So if anyone is searching for these, here's what I found:

- **Gart the Mad**, Maniacal Fallen Master - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/gart-the-mad) is for a [Fallen Overseer](http://d3db.com/npc/i/fallen-overseer), which D3DB says can spawn in Act 2 Black Canyon Bridge, Black Canyon Mines, Howling Plateau, Road to Alcarnus, and Stinging Winds.
- **Grimnight the Soulless**, Shadow of Death - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/grimnight-the-soulless) is for an [Enslaved Nightmare](http://d3db.com/npc/i/enslaved-nightmare), which D3DB says can only spawn in Act 4 Silver Spire Level 2.  I thought these could spawn on Silver Spire Level 1 as well, but cannot check at the moment.  I have this checked off on my list, I must have killed him before I knew about the achievement...
- **Hazzor the Viper**, The Sibilant - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/hazzor-the-viper) is for a [Serpent Magus](http://d3db.com/npc/i/serpent-magus), which D3DB says spawns in Act 2 Dahlgur Oasis, Khasim Outpost, The Ruins Level 1, and The Ruins Level 2.  However, I have also seen Serpent Magi spawn in The Ruined Cistern, and The City of Caldeum during the few events that happen there.
- **Jezeb the Conjuror**, Cultist Beast Caller - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/jezeb-the-conjuror) is for the higher level [Dark Summoner](http://d3db.com/npc/i/dark-summoner) that D3DB says spawns in Act 1 Cain's House (can probably disregard), Halls of Agony Level 1, Halls of Agony Level 2, Halls of Agony Level 3, Leoric's Hunting Grounds, Leoric's Manor, and Act 2 Sundered Canyon.  The post above that says it was encountered in Act 1 Halls of Agony 2 or 3 is likely correct, so check those two levels as that's much narrower.
- **Kysindra the Wretched**, Lust's Forlorn - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/kysindra-the-wretched) is for a [Hell Witch](http://d3db.com/npc/i/hell-witch), which D3DB says only spawns in Act 4 Silver Spire Level 1.  The above post says "Silver Spire Level 2?"  I could have sworn there are succubi in level 2, and if there are they are called Hell Witches as well, which would mean Kysindra could be in level 2, but I will edit after maintenance if it turns out no succubi spawn in level 2.  Plus it's always possible Kysindra still just spawns in Level 2, regardless.
- **Mage Lord Ghuyan**, Guardian Lord of Fire - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/mage-lord-ghuyan) is for a [Smoldering Construct](http://d3db.com/npc/i/smoldering-construct), which D3DB says can only spawn in Act 2, The Unknown Depths.  However, it said the same thing for Mage Lord Skomara, and I found him in the Storm Halls.
- **Marchocyas**, Winged Horror - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/marchocyas) is for a [Demonic Hellflyer](http://d3db.com/npc/i/demonic-hellflyer), which D3DB says can spawn in Act 3 Rakkis Crossing, Skycrown Battlements, Stonefort, The Barracks Level 1, and The Battlefields.  However, the post above says "I believe I encountered this in Act 4" which may very well be true.
- **Rhau'Kye**, The Eye of Flame - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/rhau-kye) is for a [Morlu Incinerator](http://d3db.com/npc/i/morlu-incinerator), which D3DB says can spawn in Act 4 Arreat Crater Level 1, The Silver Spire Level 1, and The Silver Spire Level 2.
- **Saha the Slasher**, Infected Terrifying Claws - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/saha-the-slasher) is for a [Lacuni Huntress](http://d3db.com/npc/i/lacuni-huntress), which D3DB says can spawn in Act 2 Black Canyon Mines, Howling Plateau, Khasim Outpost, Stinging Winds, and Sundered Canyon.  I'm pretty sure these also spawn in some early random Act 2 dungeons as well, though.
- **Slarg the Behemoth**, Massive Hellbeast - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/slarg-the-behemoth) is for a [Mounted Armaddon](http://d3db.com/npc/i/mounted-armaddon), which D3DB says can spawn in Act 4 Gardens of Hope 2nd Tier, Hell Rift, and The Silver Spire Level 1.  I could have sworn these can also spawn in Silver Spire Level 2.
- **Veshan the Fierce**, Cloaked by the Unseen - its [string](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster/veshan-the-fierce) is for a [Subjugator](http://d3db.com/npc/i/subjugator), which D3DB says can spawn in Act 4 Gardens of Hope 1st Tier, Gardens of Hope 2nd Tier, Hell Rift, and The Silver Spire Level 1.  Could have sworn these spawn in Silver Spire Level 2, as well.

Comment: Can you add in your answers into community wiki answer, please?

Comment: I'm hesitant to put them in the official list above since I can't confirm them, and the majority of them don't even list a definite location.  Plus a couple of them contradict the empirical list.  If I find any personally, I will add them above...

Answer (score 0):

Blarg the Imp-spawns in the desolate sands, b/f and I ran into him by accident the other day, on my map he was near the archives at the northern area, but I am not sure he would not be elsewhere given random maps

Answer (score 0):

I found The Crusher in Act III in the Keep Depths. Pretty sure it was on level 2

Answer (score -1):

Gholash is in the secret oasis. he spawsn after you hit bone piles near a little puddle of water (randomly of course)

Comment: You're thinking of Fezuul. [It even nets you the lore book *The Promises of Fezuul al-Kazaar*](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/70663/23580). Gholash might spawn in the Oasis, near the pile of bones, but it shouldn't be related to whether you hit the bones or not.