# Where do the Act 5 Unique monsters spawn for the Special Assignment / Irreplaceable You achievements?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

It looks like there is a great list for acts 1-4 here: [Where do the enemies for the unique enemy achievements spawn?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70103/where-do-the-enemies-for-the-unique-enemy-achievements-spawn)

However, I couldn't find a list for the new Act 5 achievements added in Reaper of Souls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the list, with some locations collected from http://www.d3andre.com/en/special-assignment-achievement-4.html. I haven't confirmed these locations myself but am making it community wiki so that will be easy to do. I'll put asterisks after locations that are confirmed in the table below.

- **Lacocious the Diseased**: The Plague Tunnels Level 1 **
- **Morghum the Beast**: Blood Marsh **
- **Fangbite**: Paths of the Drowned **
- **Gozmol**
- **Vilepaw**: Paths of the Drowned **
- **Slinger**: Paths of the Drowned **
- **Tadardya**: Paths of the Drowned **
- **Vek Tabok**: Passage to Corvus **
- **Vek Marru**: Passage to Corvus **
- **Nak Sarugg**: Ruins of Corvus **
- **Nak Qujin**: Ruins of Corvus **
- **Bari Hattar**: Ruins of Corvus **
- **Lograth**: Pandemonium Fortress Level 1 **
- **Valtesk the Cruel**: Pandemonium Fortress Level 1 **
- **Scythys**: Pandemonium Fortress Level 1 **
- **Razael the Feared**: Pandemonium Fortress Level 1
- **Hyadures**: Pandemonium Fortress Level 1 **
- **Ballartrask the Defiler**: Pandemonium Fortress Level 2 **
- **Zorrus**: Pandemonium Fortress Level 2 **
- **Xaphane**: Pandemonium Fortress Level 2 **
- **Rockulus**: Battlefields of Eternity **
- **Obsidious**: Battlefields of Eternity **
- **Slarth the Tunneler**: Battlefields of Eternity **
- **Burrask the Tunneler**: Battlefields of Eternity **
- **Watareus**: Battlefields of Eternity **
- **Baethus**: Battlefields of Eternity **
- **Bloone**: Realm of the Banished **
- **Erdith**: Briarthorn Cemetary **
- **Hedros**: Briarthorn Cemetary **
- **Purah**: Briarthorn Cemetary **
- **Targerious**: Briarthorn Cemetary **
- **Yellow Ledbiter**
- **Gout Foot Johnson**
- **Dale Hawthorne**: Westmarch Commons **
- **Captain Gerber**: Westmarch Commons **
- **Igor Stalfos**: Westmarch Commons **
- **Yergacheph**: Westmarch Commons **
- **Jonathan Muddlemore**
- **Matanzas the Loathsome**: Westmarch Commons **
- **Maiden of Flame** (x3): Westmarch Heights **
- **Micheboar**: Westmarch Heights **
- **Theodosia Buhre**: Westmarch Heights **
- **Sumaryss the Damned**: Westmarch Heights **
- **Pan Fezbane**: Westmarch Heights **
- **Fearby the Prowler**
- **Phyneus the Growler**: Westmarch Commons **