# Can two unique monsters spawn in the same area?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I'm trying to get both the Irreplaceable You and Special Assignment achievements, but am stuck with the last two, Hyadures and Phyneus the Growler.  According to [Where do the Act 5 Unique monsters spawn for the Special Assignment / Irreplaceable You achievements?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168873/where-do-the-act-5-unique-monsters-spawn-for-the-special-assignment-irreplacea) (and other references), I should look in Pandemonium Fortress level 1 for Hyadures and in Westmarch Commons for Phyneus.

However, other uniques can also spawn in those areas, so I want to know whether, if I should find either Captain Gerber or Dale Hawthorne, I should abandon the search in Westmarch for Phyneus or whether they can spawn in the same area *in the same game*?

And the same with Hyadures and, say, Razael or Lograth?

Comment: I feel like in my experience I certainly have seen 2 unique monsters in an area (usually a "rare" unique and a "common" unique if that makes sense).  I'll see if I can find a video of someone else finding such an occurrence.  Good luck with Hyadures, he was my last (and probably hardest) to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are playing on console or PC (probably doesn't matter) but I managed to find a video for the Playstation version where someone find Phyneus the Growler and has a bounty to kill Dale Hawthorne which should imply that they can both indeed spawn together in Westmarch Commons.

The video is here:

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that the randomisation is done server-side, so it should make no difference. As luck would have it, I've just had a (PC) game where Westmarch Commons contained four uniques: Igor Stalfos, Phyneus the Growler, Therk, Valoelle.

Comment: There you go!!!

Comment: Just need to find evidence of the equivalent case for Hyadures and I'm done. Preferably by finding him, of course!

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for Razael for a long time, it finally spawned with Valtesk (which was much more common as a spawn):

[image]

Scythys (as a bounty boss) spawned with Valtesk in an earlier game:

[image]